# OS Module: Does the file content contains string x? (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

If I get the content of a file with `ret = os.read(fd, os.path.getsize(file))`, how do I check if `ret` contains a specific string, for example `"hello world"`?

An answer on here was simply `if "hello world" not in ret:`, but this does not work anymore in python 3.4, apparently (Because of mixing bytes with unicode or something). How do I do this now?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `os.read` and file descriptors?

Comment: `if b"hello world" not in ret:` (note the `b` before the string). But why are you using `os.read()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/606199/758446 will help you get your bytestring to a string.

Comment: @JonClements I never used Python and just googled how to read a file, this method came up

Comment: Ah, google "python file I/O" to get better results.  That isn't the best or most common way to read from a file.

Comment: @Fly okay... best to avoid it then.... use `ret = open('filename').read()` insted

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks, works! I'm using os module because I never used python and just googled how to read a file, and this method came up.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Shall I answer my own question or do you want to write a "real" answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy fix is to prefix the string with `b`, so that it is treated as a **b**yte string:

```
if b"hello world" not in ret:
```

---

However I strongly recommend you to use the [builtin `open()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) and file objects, as [described on the Python I/O tutorial](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

On Python 3, strings returned by file objects are always unicode strings by default, so that you don't have to bother about byte strings and encodings.

Here is a working example:

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    file_content = f.read()

if 'hello world' not in file_content:
    ...
```